# ASP.Net Drop Down List Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datareader

I know how to query a db and get the results into a data reader and bind it to my dropdownlist element, but how do you do it without using the database?

I have years that I want to display in the dropdownlist, like:

```
 for(int i = 2010; i >=200; i--)
 {
      //make drop down list stuff here
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
for(int i = 2010; i >=200; i--)
{
     yourDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
}
```

A few considerations:

- This will add the year both to the item's Text and Value. Take a look at the other [`ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) constructors and see the options you have.
- At some point, you might need to clear existing items before populating again. If that's the case, you clear the items by doing `yourDropDown.Items.Clear();`
- `Items` is a `ListItemCollection` (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx)). So this code fits both `DropDownList` and `ListBox`, since both have the `Items` property.

Comment: Be sure you are only doing this once (ie, check IsPostBack first), otherwise you will lose your DropDownList events and selection.  Just like binding to a datasource.

Comment: @Bryan This is a good point. However, it also applies when you are loading from DB, which OP already knows how to do. So I assumed OP is already taking that into consideration.

Comment: @chris Let us know if this has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListBox("DisplayText","Value"));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx